# Как в MySQL выбрать значение поля по условию типа IF?

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется ввиду исправить идею типа "если ячейка == 0, то взять источник 2, иначе источник 1

SELECT (IF `strObjectNameBySrc1` = 0 THEN `strObjectNameBySrc2`  ELSE `strObjectNameBySrc1` END IF)  FROM `table_name` WHERE 1

Comment: [CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)

Comment: [CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) либо [IF/ELSE construct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if)